# Debian mirror growing continuesly

Tags: linux, debian, package, administration, mirroring

I maintain a private Debian mirror. A 160 GB hard disk is finished by now. I wonder if it is deleting unwanted old files. The disk usage is increasing everyday. I'd like to know how I can verify this.

Whats the best resource to learn Debian mirror administration in a deep, through manner ?

Answer (score 2):

Debian's [Setting up a Debian archive mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror) page describes in detail how to set up a mirror. They have a section on [partial mirroring](http://www.debian.org/mirror/ftpmirror#partial), which might help you save space. If you follow their methods, files that are deleted in the source archive should also be deleted in your mirror.

Comment: I am behind my college firewall and the only allowed method is http. Also is there a complete reference to learn about mirror management?

Comment: In the document I linked, they say that mirroring using FTP or HTTP could be problematic, since these service can't detect hard links.